# Fail to fetch Fetching tokens via normal OBO flow

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

I've tried to fetch token on behaf a user with MSAL.
[On-behalf-of (OBO)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV2c7.png)
code fetch token:

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredScope(scopeRequiredByAPI)]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserDetailController : ControllerBase
{
    const string scopeRequiredByAPI = "access_as_user";
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly ILogger<UserDetailController> _logger;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly AzureAdB2COpenIdConnectOptions _settings;
    public UserDetailController(ILogger<UserDetailController> logger, IUserService userService, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IOptions<AzureAdB2COpenIdConnectOptions> settings)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _userService = userService;
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<User> GetAsync()
    {
        User currentUser = new User() { DisplayName = "Son" };
        //return currentUser;
        try
        {
            var scopes = new string[] {
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
                //"User.ReadWrite.All",
                };
            var user = HttpContext?.User;
            var result = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(scopes, _settings.TenantId, _settings.SignUpSignInPolicyId, user);
```

config web app

```
builder.Services
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, 
  Constants.AzureAdB2C)
  .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
  .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))
  .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
```

config web api

```
builder.Services
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C, Constants.AzureAdB2C)
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(options =>
            {
                options.BaseUrl = GraphApiOption?.EndPoint ?? "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
                options.Scopes = GraphApiOption?.Scopes;
            })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

issue:

```
info: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
  True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:08Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] === Token Acquisition (OnBehalfOfRequest) started:
    Authority: https://hellioshop.b2clogin.com/tfp/hellioshop.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in_gk/
    Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
    ClientId: 7cc33dc4-5218-4798-a1d3-f79a782a2824
```

warn: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:08Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] Only in-memory caching is used. The cache is not persisted and will be lost if the machine is restarted. It also does not scale for a web app or web API, where the number of users can grow large. In production, web apps and web APIs should use distributed caching like Redis. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-cca-token-cache-serialization
info: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:08Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] [Instance Discovery] Skipping Instance discovery for non-AAD authority.
info: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:08Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] [Internal cache] Total number of cache partitions found while getting access tokens: 0
info: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:08Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] [FindAccessTokenAsync] Discovered 0 access tokens in cache using partition key: Ey02OURgEZIIpcqKfoU7GyOswE8Xm_5eOtv-sJBftlU
info: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:08Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] [OBO request] Fetching tokens via normal OBO flow.
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
Start processing HTTP request POST https://hellioshop.b2clogin.com/tfp/hellioshop.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in_gk/oauth2/v2.0/token
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
Sending HTTP request POST https://hellioshop.b2clogin.com/tfp/hellioshop.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in_gk/oauth2/v2.0/token
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
Received HTTP response headers after 567.4847ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
End processing HTTP request after 582.3227ms - 200
fail: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
True MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.9 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-08-13 18:22:09Z - d9208054-ea81-44cc-bf49-7ea6a2c1d874] System.Text.Json.JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment() at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read() at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerContext context) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Utils.JsonHelper.DeserializeFromJson[T](String json) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.CreateResponse[T](HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ExecuteRequestAsync[T](Uri endPoint, HttpMethod method, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean expectErrorsOn200OK, Boolean addCommonHeaders, Func`2 onBeforePostRequestData)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.GetTokenAsync(Uri endPoint, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean addCommonHeaders, Func`2 onBeforePostRequestHandler) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendHttpAndClearTelemetryAsync(String tokenEndpoint, ILoggerAdapter logger) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendTokenRequestAsync(IDictionary`2 additionalBodyParameters, String scopeOverride, String tokenEndpointOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.SendTokenRequestAsync(IDictionary`2 additionalBodyParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.OnBehalfOfRequest.FetchNewAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.OnBehalfOfRequest.RefreshRtOrFetchNewAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.OnBehalfOfRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

can you help me.tks

may you have any advice for me?

Comment: Is this correct: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`?

Comment: It’s correct. Issue at here when parse token

Comment: `System.Text.Json.JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value`. That means you receive a HTML page instead of json?